# Use Converter for static text In Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to give text for  `Binding` parameter Here is my code ..
but I just want to use converter for change text language

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding #mytext goes here#,Converter={StaticResource languageConverter}}"    
     Style="{StaticResource TbInfo}" />
```

In above textblock I want to change text using `languageConverter`

- UPDATE

Even I can bind class property directly as a string or content like

```
    public string HEADER_TEXT = {get;set;}


<TextBlock Text="{Binding HEADER_TEXT,Converter={StaticResource languageConverter}}"    
     Style="{StaticResource TbInfo}" />
```

Comment: Could you use the string table instead? Then you can use the Microsoft translations tools.. See the following link for more details on translations http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/08

Answer (score 0):

I would just add another static resource entry:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="HeaderText" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">mytext goes here</sys:String>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource HeaderText},Converter={StaticResource languageConverter}}" />
```

---

Alternately, if you really wanted to include the text inline, then you could pass it using "ConverterParameter".  But for this to work, you'd need to modify your converter class to use "parameter" if it is set.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ConverterParameter='mytext goes here',Converter={StaticResource languageConverter}}"  />
```

---

Also, I think that @StuartSmith is right, ideally you should consider using .NET's [globalization/localization framework](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Globalization-Sample-ef20151f).  This gives you better runtime performance (the localized DLLs are compiled as satellite assemblies, which effectively reduces your application's memory footprint).

Comment: Thanks for answer .. you have any Idea how to add those resources dynamically ??